# Why do I need to use as Callable on my closure for submitting to executors?

Tags: dynamic, concurrency, groovy

Why does the following groovy code pass?

```
Executor executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1)
assert executor.submit({"some value"}).get() == null
assert executor.submit({"some value"} as Callable).get() == "some value"
```

When {} instanceof Closure implements GroovyCallable extends Callable ?

What black magic is the as keyword providing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it looks like a feature of groovy compiler to prefer `Runnable` interface in `Closure` before `Callable` to avoid `Ambiguous method overloading call`.

Please take a look at the discussions https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY-4311 and https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY-3295

To get some perspective on the problem, you can take a look at the similar Java code which will fail to compile:

```
class MyClosure implements Runnable, Callable<String> {

    @Override public String call() throws Exception {
        return "some value";
    }

    @Override public void run() {
    }
}

ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
executorService.submit(new MyClosure());
```